# help in find derivative of intervals function

Tags: derivatives

if the function is $f(x) = c + (x-a) (d-c) / (b-a)$
what the derivative is $f(x) ' =$?

I tried lookup for derivatives table, but find nothing meets my question.

Conditions are $a < b$, $c < d$, $a <= x <= b$.

Comment: Your function is **linear**- of the form y= C+ Bx where B= (d- c)/(a- c) and C= c- a(d- c)/(a- c).  It's derivative is the constant *slope* of the line, B= (d- c)/(a- c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=c+x.\frac{d-c}{b-a}-a\left(\frac{d-c}{b-a}\right)$$
$$\implies f'(x)= \frac{d-c}{b-a}$$